How do I create an ETL job that runs Java using Databricks?
I'm trying to run the following connection string in Java:
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class ConnectionTest
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
      Connection connection = null;
      try
      {
         Class.forName("com.netsuite.jdbc.openaccess.OpenAccessDriver");
         String connectionURL =
                  "jdbc:ns://<ServiceHost>:1708;" +
                  "ServerDataSource=NetSuite.com;" +
                  "Encrypted=1;" +
                  "NegotiateSSLClose=false;" +
                  "CustomProperties=(AccountID=<accountID>;RoleID=<roleID>)";
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "User", "Password");
         System.out.println("Connection success");
      }
      finally
      {
         if (connection != null)
               connection.close();
      }
   }
} 

I want to run the script using a Databricks workflow. Ultimately, my job will be passing a last modified date with a primary key to extract only the recent data and then saving it to S3 storage location. For this question, I just need to have the above run using a job.
Assuming I have the Java code in a file called fetchDataTest.java, what would my Databricks job look entail? Would I need a notebook to run it- or could I just run it directly? What compute would I use? A single-node cluster?

Please refer java spark dataframe documentation - https://www.baeldung.com/spark-dataframes
